# Having difficulty resizing an image with Css

Tags: html, css

I've recently been learning html,CSS and JS. Html and js have been mostly fine, however I've been having issues learning CSS. Particularly, I'll find that when resizing an image, any attempt to do so through an External CSS file will not be applied. However if I do so through a `style="width: 100px; height: 100px"` inside my html, it works fine. This happens sometimes with other style tags as well. Usually the rest of the CSS works fine except for certain parts. Any help and tips on this is appreciated.

```css
.jumbo {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <img src="images/FrontPicture.jpeg" alt="main display" class="jumbo" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
   <h1>Filler Text</h1>
   <p class="subhead">small filler text</p>
   <img src="" alt="pointer" class="scroll hide-mobile show-desktop">
</section>
```

Comment: Your CSS sets it to `100%` instead of `100px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should display images with `display:block` property. The default is `display:inline` and that creates some problems. Below you have examples how to add dimensions to the image. You need to specify only 1 dimension and the other will have a default width or height set to auto and browers calculate it automatically. (You don't need to write it anymore).

```css
img{display:block;margin:10px}

#img-1{width:100%}
#img-2{width:100px}
#img-3{height:75px}
```

```html
<img id="img-1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x100/fff000" alt="">
<img id="img-2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ff0000" alt="">
<img id="img-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x120/0000ff" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you, setting it to display:block fixed this. I think the reasoning for the other problem was a missing semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Images are an "inline" element by default in HTML. Setting sizing on inline elements in CSS rarely works as you expect.

```
.jumbo {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Should get you the intended result

Comment: Thank you, using "display: block;" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the specificity by

```
.parent > img.jumbo {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

And see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the in-line styles of height and width from the image tag in order to see the styles from you css class. In-line styles will always overwrite any css.

```
<section class="parent">
   <img src="images/FrontPicture.jpeg" alt="main display" class="jumbo">
   <h1>Filler Text</h1>
   <p class="subhead">small filler text</p>
   <img src="" alt="pointer" class="scroll hide-mobile show-desktop">
</section>
```

Also, assuming that by external css you mean a separate style sheet, i hope you have linked your style sheet with the HTML.

Comment: Sorry I probably made that confusing with the way I had the code linked. I added the inline-style after the css wasn't working.I'll edit the original post to make that clearer.